# AngularJS: Using function in ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using ng-disabled in my view like this I have truthy conditions

```
 md-button.md-primary.md-raised flex="20" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || form.$pristine || day == 0 || leaveapplication.reason == null" ng-click="save(starts_on, ends_on, leave_type_id, period1, period2)" Apply
```

So I'm gonna use function in my ng-disabled this time:

```
 md-button.md-primary.md-raised ng-disabled="buttonChecker()" ng-click="save(starts_on, ends_on, leave_type_id)" Apply
```

Now how can I put my condition in my function like `form.$valid` and `form.$pristine` the other condition is easy like `day == 0`, but the other conditions are hard for me.

Comment: Not able to follow your requirement or issue

Comment: are you asking, how would you be ale to access `form` from function ?

Comment: @SachetGupta yes

Comment: access it directly from `$scope`, ex: `$scope.formName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just access it with `$scope` where the name of the form is binded to `$scope.nameOfForm`. I don't know where your other variables like `day` or `leaveapplication.reason` are defined so I just inserted them blankly. You have to edit this part to make it work but I think this will show you how to achieve what you trying to.

View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <form name="myForm">
      <input type="text" name="test" ng-model="test">
      <button ng-disabled="buttonChecker();">
        Some Button
      </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

AngularJS Application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.buttonChecker = function () {
      return $scope.myForm.$invalid 
                || $scope.myForm.$pristine 
                || $scope.day === 0 
                || $scope.leaveapplication.reason === null;
    };
});
```

#### > [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xb9y4t68/1/)

Comment: let me try this

Comment: Myform is the name of the form??

Comment: Yea, as you can see in the HTML markup. `<form name="myForm">`

Comment: he cant read my function when a load the page its already enable not disabled

Comment: yes i will mark this right if it is working do u have plunker?

Comment: can u give me an example for $prestine and $invalid dont mind the other condition i can handle that :)

Comment: let me check this

Comment: @wiwit please check the updated version of the plnkr: http://jsfiddle.net/xb9y4t68/1/

Comment: why cant be reached?

Comment: What cant be reached? I also added the link to the answer.

Comment: the link cant be reach

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141873/discussion-between-wiwit-and-lin).

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the form on your function.

```
 md-button.md-primary.md-raised ng-disabled="buttonChecker(formName)" ng-click="save(starts_on, ends_on, leave_type_id)" Apply
```

and have the buttonChecker check the form using

```
$scope.buttonChecker = function (formName) {
  return formName.$invalid || formName.$pristine;      
};
```